# How to write summary log using tensorflow for logistic regression on MNIST data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression, tensorboard, mnist

I am new with `tensorflow` and implementation of `tensorboard`. This is my very first experience to implement `logistic regression` on MNIST data using tensorflow. I have successfully implemented logistic regression on data and now I am trying to log summary to log file using `tf.summary .fileWriter`.

Here is my code which affects the summary parameter

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 10)) 

loss_op = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, pred)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss_op)
tf.summary.scalar("training_accuracy", accuracy_op)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

And this is how I am training my model

```
with tf.Session() as sess:   
    sess.run(init)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)

    for iter in range(50):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        _, loss, tr_acc,summary = sess.run([optimizer_op, loss_op, accuracy_op, summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        summary = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        writer.add_summary(summary, iter)
```

After adding the summary line to get merged summary, I am getting below error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): 
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_37' 
with dtype float and shape [?,10]
```

This error points to the declaration of `Y`

```
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 10))
```

Can you please help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you are running your code in some kind of jupyter environment. Try restarting the kernel/runtime and run everything again. Running the code twice in graph mode does not work in jupyter well. If I run my code, below, first time it does not return any errors, when I run it second time (w/o restarting kernel/runtime) then it crashes the same way as yours does.

I was too lazy to check it on actual model so my `pred=y`. ;)
But the code below does not crash, so you should be able to adapt it to your needs. I've tested it in Google Colab.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784), name='x-input')
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 10), name='y-input')

pred = y
loss_op = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, pred)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
  tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss_op, collections=["train_summary"])
  tf.summary.scalar("training_accuracy", accuracy_op, collections=["train_summary"])

with tf.Session() as sess:   
  summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all(key='train_summary')
  train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)
  sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer()])

  for iter in range(50):
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(1)
    loss, acc, summary = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy_op, summary_op], feed_dict={x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, iter)
```

Comment: Thanks, MP. I am sorry to replying late. Somehow, with your given suggestion I able to reach to the final result. Though, I did not understand why every time we need to restart the kernel to run code related to sensor flow session?

Comment: I think it is becasue of the fact that you cannot free GPU memory once you allocate it. Then you do not remove the graph form the memory so it is stuck there. If you used different memory allocation method for the graph (allow_growth=True) then you probably may run it a couple of times without restarting kernel before you run into OOM issues, but then I think it is better to restart it every single time - there is a keyboard shortcut for that afair O,O.